# (concatenation) add 4 "char *" macros together in C

Tags: c, macros, concatenation

I have four `char *` macros that I want to put together but I only saw answers with two `char *`, is there a way to do it?

Here is the code:

```
#define one   "\x0C\x03\xD1\x00"
#define two   "\xC1\x03\x1A\x0C"
#define three "\xA2\x1A\x0D\x00"
#define four  "\xD4\x1C\x4C\x0A"

char *concat(const char *s1, const char *s2, const char *s3, const char *s4) {
    char *cat = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + strlen(s3) + strlen(s4) + 1);
    strcpy(cat, s1);
    strcpy(cat, s2);
    strcpy(cat, s3);
    strcat(cat, s4);
    return cat;
}
```

Comment: The defines are string literals. They are of type `char []`. That is, they are `char` arrays. So you can use them the same ways as you are doing for `char *`.

Comment: There are a few odd things about your code though. 1. Why are you doing `strcpy` for `s2`, `s3`? That's pointless as each `strcpy` overwrites previous `strcpy`. Maybe you meant to use `strcat` even for those. 2. The strings seem to contain some binary (non-ascii) values. Depending on what you are trying to achieve that is probably not the right thing to do. In particular it is not safe to use such "strings" with the string functions.

Answer (score 1):

In your function implementation for example the second call of `strcpy` overwrites the first string in the array pointed to by the variable `cat`.

strcpy(cat, s1);
  strcpy(cat, s2);

I think you mean the following

```
char * concat(const char * s1, const char * s2, const char * s3, const char * s4) {
  char * cat = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+strlen(s3)+strlen(s4)+1);

  strcpy( cat, s1 );
  strcat( cat, s2 );
  strcat( cat, s3 );
  strcat( cat, s4 );

  return cat;
}
```

A more efficient approach is the following

```
char * concat(const char * s1, const char * s2, const char * s3, const char * s4) {
  size_t n1 = strlen( s1 );
  size_t n2 = strlen( s2 ); 
  size_t n3 = strlen( s3 ); 
  size_t n4 = strlen( s4 );

  char *cat = malloc( n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + 1 );

  strcpy( cat, s1 );
  strcpy( cat + n1, s2 );
  strcpy( cat + n1 + n2, s3 );
  strcpy( cat + n1 + n2 + n3, s4 );

  return cat;
}
```

As for these macros

```
#define one   "\x0C\x03\xD1\x00"
#define two   "\xC1\x03\x1A\x0C"
#define three "\xA2\x1A\x0D\x00"
#define four  "\xD4\x1C\x4C\x0A"
```

then the first and the third macros contain terminating zeroes.  If you want to copy them in the destination string you have to yse the standard function `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`. In this case the function can look like

```
char * concat(const char * s1, const char * s2, const char * s3, const char * s4, size_t n )
{
    size_t length = 4 * n + 1;

    char * cat = malloc( length );

    memcpy( cat, s1, n );
    memcpy( cat + n, s2, n );
    memcpy( cat + 2 *n, s3, n );
    memcpy( cat + 3 *n, s4, n );
    cat[4 & n] = '\0';

    return cat;
}
```

However there will be a problem that the string contains embedded zero characters. So maybe there is no sense to append the result string with the terminating zero.

Comment: Perhaps `const char * s1` -> `const char * const s1` would be better? Ditto for the others

Comment: Not going to work for the data presented. (It contains NUL characters)

Comment: as @ikegami noticed none of our solutions will work as string literals contain zeroes.

Comment: @ikegami Standard C string functions do not check whether a passed pointer is equal to NULL. It is the responsibility of the client of the function to guarantee that the passed pointers are not equal to NULL.

Comment: I didn't say `NULL`, I said NUL character (`U+0000, '\0'`). `strlen` and other string functions aren't going to work.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow All string literals are 0-terminated automatically. The first and the third one contain two zeroes.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, but it seems he wants to copy only four characters of the macros.

Answer (score 1):

Since `one`, `two`, `three`, `four` are macros expanding directly to string constants, you can simply do this:

```
char result[] = one two three four;
```

After macro expansion it will turn into

```
char result[] = "\x0C\x03\xD1\x00" "\xC1\x03\x1A\x0C" "\xA2\x1A\x0D\x00" "\xD4\x1C\x4C\x0A";
```

and adjacent string literals are concatenated automatically.

Note that this will not work if you replace macros with variables, e.g. `char *one = "\x0C\x03\xD1\x00";`.

For more general approaches to concatenating arbitrary strings (not necessarily macros), see other answers.

Comment: what about this `char *one = "one";char *two = "two";char *three = "three";char *four = "four";` will it be same good? You  put mess into beginner head

Comment: @P__J__ The question explicitly says "macros". But I've edited the answer to clearly say that it only works on macros.

Comment: sohere you have macros `#define one   (const char[]){"asdfg"}
#define two   (const char[]){"12345"}
#define three (const char[]){"@#$%^"}
#define four  (const char[]){"ZXCV"}` is your solution any good?

Comment: @P__J__ Oh well, I've changed the wording to be even more precise. I'm pretty sure that by *"`char *` macros"* OP meant "macros expanding to string constants".

Comment: @P__J__: `char *one = "one";` will expand to a bizarre syntax error (`error: expected identifier or '('`), which will teach the OP a lesson about macros :) see https://godbolt.org/z/pjuf5p

Answer (score 1):

Given the presence of NUL characters, those aren't strings (since those are NUL-terminated), so string functions such as `strlen` can't be used, so the sizes of the arrays would need to be passed to the concatenating function.

```
 char *buf_concat(
    char **buf_ptr, size_t *size_ptr,
    const char *buf1, size_t n1,
    const char *buf2, size_t n2,
    const char *buf3, size_t n3,
    const char *buf4, size_t n4
 ) {
    *size_ptr = n1+n2+n3+n4;
    char *buf_ptr; = malloc(*size_ptr);
    if (!*buf_ptr)
       return NULL;

    char *p = *buf_ptr;
    memcpy(p, buf1, n1);  p += n1;
    memcpy(p, buf2, n2);  p += n2;
    memcpy(p, buf3, n3);  p += n3;
    memcpy(p, buf4, n4);
    return *buf_ptr;
 }

 char *buf;
 size_t buf_size;
 buf_concat(
    &buf,  &buf_size,
    one,   sizeof(one  )-1,
    two,   sizeof(two  )-1,
    three, sizeof(three)-1,
    four,  sizeof(four )-1
 );
```

(We must subtract 1 because `sizeof("\xC1\x03\x1A\x0C")` is `5`.)

But there's a programmer's adage that says that if you're using numbered variables, you should be using an array. That wouldn't really help here because you're trying to abstract away something that can't be abstracted away.

```
 size_t buf_size =
      sizeof(one  )-1
    + sizeof(two  )-1
    + sizeof(three)-1
    + sizeof(four )-1;

 char *buf = malloc(buf_size);
 char *p = buf;
 memcpy(p, one,   sizeof(one  )-1);  p += sizeof(one  )-1;
 memcpy(p, two,   sizeof(two  )-1);  p += sizeof(two  )-1;
 memcpy(p, three, sizeof(three)-1);  p += sizeof(three)-1;
 memcpy(p, four,  sizeof(four )-1);
```

But since `"aaa" "bbb"` is the same thing as `"aaabbb"`, we can simplify!

```
 size_t buf_size = sizeof(one two three four) - 1;
 char *buf = malloc(buf_size);
 memcpy(buf, one two three four, buf_size);
```

(Thanks to @chqrlie for reminding me I wanted to mention this shortcut all along!)

Comment: I was in Pittsburgh a week ago and have not adjusted for jetlag yet :)